# Bad Gateway - Azure Logic App - Invoke an Http Request

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-entra-id, onpremises-gateway

I have an HTTP Rest API which works on POST Method with some XML input and produces the output also in XML format.

I'm able to get the response in Postman for the above scenario.

In Azure Logic App, I have tried with the below steps but it is failed due to bad gateway.

[image]

I cannot post my rest api, but you can try with the rest api that takes xml format input and produces xml format output.

And we are using the action called "**[Http With Microsoft entra Id (preauthorized)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/webcontents/)**" - On-premises data gateway.

We installed [on-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install) in local and created the same resource in Azure by linking with the on-premises data gateway connection.

- Azure Logic App, On-premises data gateway, Azure On-premises data gateway --> all resources are in same location.

Could anyone please help me what is the wrong I did or any step I missed?

Comment: Have you tried using `HTTP` connector?

Comment: Hi @IkhtesamAfrin, thanks for prompt response.
https://i.imgur.com/BlZEdlO.png - This is the connector/action we're instructed to use in the team by checking the gateways option checkbox

Comment: I might not be able to guide you due to limited access on on-premises data gateway